# SXA Custom Experience Button for Page Content Rendering Variant Field

Tags: sxa

I know how to add a Custom Experience (field) Button to a Rendering when it's directly added to a page inside a placeholder, however, I have a slightly different scenario.

I have a partial design that has a page content rendering with a variant selected.  This gets used on the page design. So the content editor is adding a page using Experience Editor. I am not seeing how to add an experience editor button in this instance.

More specifically - I have an Article page, when it is being content edited in Experience Editor I need them to be able to click a button to modify 2 fields that make up the article template as they are not actually displayed on this page but belong with the content (eg. summary text field).  Because the page content rendering is on the partial design - I don't get the usual buttons appearing at the top when on an individual page apart from field level.

I have an image as the first field - and so was thinking it would be good if I could add a custom button there.  But even going to this field specifically and adding a custom experience button it is not appearing.

[image]

My rendering variant:

[image]

The partial design contains the Page Content rendering - which has the buttons I'm used to, but the page itself is going to be experience edited rather than the partial.

[image]

My custom experience button:
[image]

My template where I have added a custom experience editor button to the Banner Image
[image]

My rendering variant - responsive image - tied to the Banner Image field

[image]

**UPDATE**- strangely now I am seeing a disabled experience editor button in my image context menu.  But I can't figure out why it is disabled - unless it's because it's getting confused about trying to edit teaser fields that are part of the parent article template.

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with field renderers for "ArticleImage" and "Article Image"?

Comment: @PeterProcházka are you saying to include screenshots of the section wrapper and responsive image field properties?

Comment: @PeterProcházka I have added more information - it seems like the button is now appearing but it's disabled so I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: is it perhaps that you didn't add the ArticleImage field to your custom button? i only see the teaser Image and Teaser Title in the fields section in the button.

Comment: @MenahAlasmy What I want to do is give the content editor a way of updating fields which aren't rendered as part of this page content rendering.  The article teaserimage and title fields belong on the article but are not displayed on this page.  If I were to add the page content rendering to the page, I could attach the button to there, but it is added to the partial view so not seen when editing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's an easier way to expose fields for editing that aren't displayed on the page. I wasn't aware of the Page Metadata, Other button on the Experience Accelerator tab.

[image]